# Using PDO Prepared Statement and Incrementing a column value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read this thread: [Issues incrementing a field in MySQL/PHP with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835024/issues-incrementing-a-field-in-mysql-php-with-prepared-statements) but didn't see the answer to my problem.

```
PDOStatement Object
(

    [queryString] => UPDATE user_alerts SET notif = ? + 2 WHERE ( user_id = ? )   

)

$stmt->execute( array( 'notif', '1' ) );
```

As far as I can tell, all this is correct.

When the above code executes, it sets the notif column equal to 2 irregardless of what the value of the notif column is.  It's as if the SQL is reading like `SET notif = 2` instead of `SET notif = notif + 2`

I haven't been able to figure it out and would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE user_alerts SET notif = notif + 2 WHERE ( user_id = :userid )';
$prepStatement = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$prepStatement->execute(array(':userid' => $userid));
```

You can't bind a column name to a prepared statement.

Answer (score 6):

Using parameters is not just a simple text replacement. You can't replace a column name with a parameter. MySQL will interpret your query as if you had written this:

```
UPDATE user_alerts SET notif = 'notif' + 2 WHERE ( user_id = ? )
```

The string `'notif'` is converted to zero for the addition.

Try this query instead:

```
UPDATE user_alerts SET notif = notif + 2 WHERE ( user_id = ? )
```