# Decrement column value on multiple rows with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a MySql products table (accessed via PHP and PDO) with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Products are shown via order field. When I remove a product, I would like to decrement order values for all the following rows (i.e. if I remove product with `order=2`, I want to update the following row from `order=3` to `order=2`, the next from `order=4` to `order=3`, and so on...).

I obviously would like to do this query in the most efficient way with PDO. I've found [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284470/using-pdo-prepared-statement-and-incrementing-a-column-value) and tried the following statement in PhpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE products SET order = order - 1 WHERE (order>2)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = order - 1 WHERE (order>2)' at line 1
```

What am I missing? And then, what is the correct way to write it with PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ORDER` is the reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Use *backticks* to escape it:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `order` = `order` - 1 WHERE (`order` > 2);
```