# updating row by adding +1 using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add +1 to a row in my table and using the following code

```
 try {
$query = $con->prepare( "UPDATE sitename SET hits = hits + 1
             WHERE sitename = ?" );
$query->bindValue( 1, $url );
$query->execute();
// show error

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I think the table is set up right for the field hits, the type is `int(11)`

As you can see I am trying to learn as I go,  also I have read a few questions on here that give a similar answers to the same problem but adapted the code to work.... in this case not to work.

in the above code I bind the value sitename, do I need to do the same for hits?

the following code does nothing to the row at all,

the following question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284470/using-pdo-prepared-statement-and-incrementing-a-column-value) has a very detailed error and this is where i got the base of this code from, like I said I have done some searching around before posting I just think I'm missing something or completely not understanding the problem.

This code does not echo an error too.

Comment: Check the bindValue documentation: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: "in this case not to work." How does it fail? What is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PDO Prepared Statement and Incrementing a column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284470/using-pdo-prepared-statement-and-incrementing-a-column-value)

Comment: `SET hits = hits + 1,`  <<< see that trailing comma? Using http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have thrown you something. `$something = "Syntax error.";`

Comment: *"This code does not echo an error too."*-  (see ^ above) - [Because, you're not checking for errors, *period*.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks im now adding it, i understand people get annoyed with dumb questions and down vote but an explanation to why would be nice instead of downvoting and running as i will not know for future reference :).

Comment: `SET hits = hits + 1,` >>> `SET hits = hits + 1` there. That's an *"in other words..."* to my previous comment. If that doesn't fix it, edit your question with the proper syntax. One reason why you got downvoted may have been because questions like these show up rather often and many fail to check for errors, in turn, avoiding the question altogether. Many low reppers would've jumped on this question to make points, but Stack sees this as being off-topic. We/I don't make the rules, Stack does ;-) and you're welcome.

Comment: where are you putting that exceptions? It needs to be placed right after your connection. You are using PDO to connect with, correct? and the other link given should have been in English http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php - edit: as per given by @leonardo_palma

Comment: See Darwin's answer below. Let him know if it works or not. @RickNash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions, two answers.

First, as @Fred points out, remove the comma after `hits = hits + 1` and the `UPDATE` statement will work.

Second,

> in the above code I bind the value sitename, do I need to do the same for hits?

No. You use bind variables to pass data between the SQL code and the client code (in this case, your php code.) Updating the value of `hits` is handled entirely within the SQL and is not passed in or out.

With PDO you can also use *named* bind variables, which would look like this:

```
$query = $con->prepare( "UPDATE sitename SET hits = hits + 1
                           WHERE sitename = :url" );
```

and then either

```
$query->bindParam(':url', $url);
$query->execute();
```

or simply

```
$query->execute(array(':url' => $url));
```

The above code has no error handling, as that was not the issue I was attempting to address. Error handling is important, but in this case I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Because that wasn't part of the question. I leave that as an exercise to the reader, but thanks for reminding me to mention it.

Comment: And now he does. He can study up and try to figure it out on his own, and if he still has questions he can come back and ask them.

Comment: What you have done for me here is exactly what i was needing
:). i have fixed my code and now looking into error reporting as the code i posted above was not the whole page just the section that didnt work that made it hard for me to troubleshoot so i took this answer and tested it on its own and fixed the issues

thx again